# Why does my swift package manager takes forever to load?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, package

I can normally access a GitHub address on the browser, but when I copy the https address to the spm, it just load forever and always end up with “curl time out”. I’m current in China and I’m using proxy, but I’m sure the proxy is working fine.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

The browser proxy is something different that system proxy.  You can try to set `http.proxy` in your terminal and then try to check if it's working.